# Aggregate dictionary values with different function

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which basically it's look like this:

```
dict = {'A': [1,5,6,7],
        'B':[1,8,8]}
```

I want to grp by keys and aggregate values with different function. i.e mean or standard deviation

Mean:

```
result = {'A':4.75, 'B': 5.6}
```

etc

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dictionary comprehension and functions from [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html):

```
from statistics import mean, stdev

d = {'A': [1,5,6,7], 'B':[1,8,8]}

d_mean = {k:round(mean(v), 2) for k,v in d.items()}
# {'A': 4.75, 'B': 5.67}

d_std = {k:round(stdev(v), 2) for k,v in d.items()}
# {'A': 2.63, 'B': 4.04}
```